# How to use Meteor Collection Helpers with Angular-Meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am hoping to use `dburles:collection-helpers` with my Angular-Meteor project.

**First up: is this at all supported?**

I have found a couple of references ([here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/589) and [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/225)) indicating there is a way, but I could not use those to make it work for me.

In my project I have `quotes` and `authors`. Following the example on the [package page](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers), I have set up the following:

**model/quotes.js**

```
Quotes = new Mongo.Collection("quotes");

Quotes.helpers({
  author: function() {
    return Authors.findOne(this.authorId);
  }
});
```

**model/authors.js**

```
Authors = new Mongo.Collection("authors");

Authors.helpers({
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  },
  quotes: function() {
    return Quotes.find({
      authorId: this._id
    });
  }
});
```

**client/quotes/controllers/quotesList.ng.js**

```
angular.module("quotez").controller("QuotesListCtrl", function($scope, $meteor) {

    $scope.quotes = $meteor.collection(Quotes);

});
```

**client/quotes/views/quotes-list.ng.html**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
    <p>{{quote.text}}</p>
    <p>{{quote.author().fullName()}}</p>
    <p><span ng-repeat="tag in quote.tags">{{tag}}&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p><a href="/quotes/{{quote._id}}">Show details</a></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above is supposed to return a list of all quotes with

- the quote text,
- the quote author,
- and all related tags.

The author, which is stored in a seperate collection, is shown as `{{quote.author().fullName()}}` in the HTML output, however (i.e., does not appear to be interpreted).

Is this something that should work and I am doing wrong (if so: how can it be fixed), or am I trying to do something that is not supported seeing how Angular is involved as well?

TIA,

Matt

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I dind't try much further, if I recall correctly. I got some answers [on the Meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/does-dburles-collection-helpers-work-with-angular-meteor/12800), though, maybe they can put you on track.